# Angular js - best way to use jQuery function in my case

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and using a jQuery plugin(Nice Scroll) in multiple elements in my projects. I have the following code and it's working well.

**Service**

```
.service('nicescrollService', function() {
        var ns = {};
        ns.niceScroll = function(selector, color, cursorWidth) {
            $(selector).niceScroll({
                cursorcolor: color,
                cursorborder: 0,
                cursorborderradius: 0,
                cursorwidth: cursorWidth,
                bouncescroll: true,
                mousescrollstep: 100
            });
        }

        return ns;
    })
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('niceScroll', ['nicescrollService', function(nicescrollService){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {

                //Scrollbar for HTML(not mobile) but not for login page
                if (!$('html').hasClass('ismobile')) {
                    if (!$('.login-content')[0]) {
                        nicescrollService.niceScroll('html', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)', '5px');
                    }

                    //Scrollbar Tables
                    if ($('.table-responsive')[0]) {
                        nicescrollService.niceScroll('.table-responsive', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '5px');
                    }

                    //Scrill bar for Chosen
                    if ($('.chosen-results')[0]) {
                        nicescrollService.niceScroll('.chosen-results', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '5px');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```

**HTML**

```
<html data-ng-app="xxx" data-nice-scroll></html>
<table class="table-responsive" data-nice-scroll></table>
....
```

I have some more elements I need to use this plugin with different settings. So what I'm doing is correct? or is there any other smarter ways in Angular to handle this case?

Regards,
Rushenn

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the service, if you need to use Jquery selector it's better to use it in the directive's link property like :

```
.directive('niceScroll', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {

                scope.niceScroll = function(selector, color, cursorWidth) {
                    $(selector).niceScroll({
                        cursorcolor: color,
                        cursorborder: 0,
                        cursorborderradius: 0,
                        cursorwidth: cursorWidth,
                        bouncescroll: true,
                        mousescrollstep: 100
                    });
                };

                //Scrollbar for HTML(not mobile) but not for login page
                if (!$('html').hasClass('ismobile')) {
                    if (!$('.login-content')[0]) {
                        scope.niceScroll('html', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)', '5px');
                    }

                    //Scrollbar Tables
                    if ($('.table-responsive')[0]) {
                        scope.niceScroll('.table-responsive', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '5px');
                    }

                    //Scrill bar for Chosen
                    if ($('.chosen-results')[0]) {
                        scope.niceScroll('.chosen-results', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', '5px');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }])
```